# Can free any index of 2D Array of Chars

Tags: c

I currently have a queue struct defined as

```
typedef struct {
        int size;
        char** data;
        unsigned count;
        unsigned head;
} queue;
```

It is initialized with

```
Q->size = DEFAULTSIZE; 
Q->data = malloc(sizeof(char*) * QSIZE); 
Q->count = 0; 
Q->head = 0;
```

Whenever I enqueue something,

```
//item is a char*
Q->data[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * item_length);
Q->data[i] = item;

//If I was to do free(Q->data[i]); at this point, I would get an error as stated below
```

The issue is that whenever I dequeue, and want to free `Q->data[i]` I get a WRITE error on the line that I am freeing on. Although using `printf("%s", Q->data[i]);` seems to work fine telling me that I have access to that item.
Any advice?

Comment: Some advice: post a [mcve].

Comment: You're allocating, then stomping where you put the pointer. Do you mean `strcpy()`?

Comment: @tadman This is just an example, ideally when I dequeue I want to strcpy the item that was dequeued and return the copy of it, then free the item that was actually IN the queue. However, I'm unable to free the item that was in the q->data[i]

Comment: You trashed your allocation, then you tried to delete a constant string, presumably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably mean is this:

```c
Q->data[i] = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
strcpy(Q->data[i], item);
```

Comment: correct, but my issue is that I am unable to free(Q->data[i]) at any point and instantly get an error on that line.

Comment: You get that error because you tried to `free()` something that was not previously allocated. This code *will* work. Your code is akin to `Q->data[i] = "test"` then `free(Q->data[i])` which is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: You must pay **extremely close attention** to every allocation. I would initialize this with `Q->data[i] = NULL` and only populate it if/when `item` gets copied over. Do not pre-allocate. This will leak memory.

Comment: oh I see now, I didn't realize that using strcpy was the correct choice instead of Q->data[i] = item. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 strcpy(Q->data[i], item);
```

Instead of

```
 Q->data[i] = item;
```

You are facing this error because you are trying to del a constant pointer!